# Excel VBA loop with changing range references

Tags: excel, vba, loops, reference

I've got an excel chart with many series, and was looking to get VBA's help to automate some of the repetitive tasks of adding reference cells to the labels on the data series.

Using the Record Macro function, I got the following lines of code that do the work I need performed, but I'm stuck at getting the Range reference to update in the row with "='C'!$M$74:$T$74".

I'd like to get the 74 to be a dynamic i+4 as it goes through the loop (so that for series 70, the reference is "='C'!$M$74:$T$74", series 71 the reference is "='C'!$M$75:$T$75", and so on).

```
Sub UpdateLabelRanges()
'
' UpdateLabelRanges Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
Dim i As Integer
For i = 70 To 250

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
        InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "='C'!$M$74:$T$74", 0
    Selection.ShowRange = True
    Selection.ShowValue = False
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).HasLeaderLines = False

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Then concatenate `i + 4` into the formula.

Comment: "='C'!$M$" & i+4 & ":$T$" & i+4

Comment: `"='C'!$M$" & i + 4 & ":$T$" & i + 4`